# ¿como podría lograr hacer este carrusel en wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, slider, carrusel, modificaciones

este es el carrusel que deseo hacer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

donde el ítem del centro se agranda un poco como para resaltar ante los demás. estoy buscando un plugin en la tienda pero ninguno se parece. Soy nuevo en Wordpress, nunca he trabajado con el, es mi primera vez.

¿Que he probado hasta ahora?

instalé varios plugins: Smart Slider 3 y otros 2 que no recuerdo. Smart slider muestra una sola imagen por vez, no muestra los 3 ítems, los otros eran menos parecidos.

Tengo unas preguntas:

1. Cuándo le pasan un diseño de este tipo como empiezan? lo ideal sería buscar un plugin lo más parecido y modificarlo hasta que quede igual?
2. las modificaciones se tienen que hacer en el archivo functions .php? manejo muy poco php, tenía entendido que wordpress era más para diseñadores que no tenían mucho conocimiento de programación pero veo que para una simple modificación hay que hacer muchas cosas.

Algún consejo de alguien con experiencia en esto?

Agradecería su ayuda de antemano. Saludos!

Comment: Lo quieres gratuito o también puedes comprar puglins¿? En versión de pago hay algunos muy buenos.

Comment: preferiría gratuito. Cuándo realizan una página para un cliente como manejan lo de los plugins? me refiero a que si eso va incluido en el presupuesto que ustedes le dan al cliente? antes de enviar el presupuesto ya ustedes saben cuales plugins y cuántos van a usar? cuáles serán de pago y cuáles no?

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo varios pluggin:

*Ultra Portfolio

*All Around

*Royal Slider

*Slider Pro

Algunos son de pago pero otros son gratis (o por lo menos antes lo eran).

Espero que te sirvan, ya me contaras. Tiene muchos diseños parecidos a lo que solicitas, aunque  a lo mejor hay alguno que te guste más.

Un saludo!

Comment: Hola amigo, los estuve revisando y todos son de pago, los busqué por el administrador de plugins de wordpress y ninguno apareció, una pregunta... Cuándo realizas una página para un cliente como manejas lo de los plugins? me refiero a que si eso va incluido en el presupuesto que ustedes le dan al cliente? antes de enviar el presupuesto ya ustedes saben cuales plugins y cuántos van a usar? cuáles serán de pago y cuáles no?

Comment: Depende, si el plugin es de un único pago, le incluyo desde el 80% hasta el 100% del precio en el presupuesto (depende del beneficio), pero si el plugin es de suscripción se lo hago saber, si esta dispuesto a pagar mes a mes adelante, si no lo esta, le busco otra solución de un único pago o gratuita. El presupuesto puede cambiar algo respecto al principio, ya que tu puedes hacer una página el cliente quiere q cambies algo especifico, pero para ello necesitas un plugin de pago... pues se lo informas y se lo añades al presupuesto. El hosting web y dominio también se lo incluyo en el presupuesto.